# Accessing partitions in Platform cache

Tags: platform-cache

I have created a couple of partitions in the platform cache of my Org.One of them is default. As per the documentation to access the default partition mentioning the name of the partition is enough whereas for the no default one we have to mention the namespace as well.But I have tried removing the namespace for the non default one and the logic still works. Did I miss something here?

Ex: lets say A is default and B is not.

Accessing partition A should be `Cache.Org.getPartition('A');`
Accessing partition B should be `Cache.Org.getPartition('local.B');` But `Cache.Org.getPartition('B')` works as well.